Misunderstanding in Bayesian model averaging
I'm making my first attempt at understanding and implementing Bayesian model averaging, to make a weighted mix of several competing models. Many of the sources that I am reading make a similar claim that I do not understand. I'm hoping that someone here is able to clear up my confusion. Here is my understanding of the basic idea:

Given competing models $M_1,\ldots,M_K$ and some training data $y_{\text{train}}$ the weighted model average is
$$p(y)=\sum_{k=1}^Kp(y|M_k)p(M_k|y_{\text{train}}),\tag{1}$$
where $p(M_k|y_{\text{train}})$ is the posterior probability of model $M_k$ being correct given the training data. The posterior probabilities add up to 1, so they can be viewed as weights. The posterior probability for model $M_k$ is given by
$$p(M_k|y_{\text{train}})=\frac{p(y_{\text{train}}|M_k)p(M_k)}{\sum_{l=1}^Kp(y_{\text{train}}|M_l)p(M_l)}.\tag{2}$$

It is not clear to me why the posterior probabilities should add up to $1$. It is clear that the expression on the right hand side of $(2)$ adds up to $1$ when summed over $k=1,\ldots,K$, but it is not clear to me why that should be the posterior probability. It looks a lot like an application of Bayes rule:
$$p(M_k|y_{\text{train}})=\frac{p(y_{\text{train}}|M_k)p(M_k)}{p(y_{\text{train}})},\tag{3}$$
and this would give $(2)$ if we would have
$$p(y_{\text{train}})=\sum_{l=1}^Kp(y_{\text{train}}|M_l)p(M_l).$$
This looks a lot like an application of the law of total probability, except that the $M_k$ need not be mutually exclusive. So I am not convinced $(3)$ holds.
As an extreme example, we can add another model to the mix by setting $M_{K+1}=M_1$. Now if $p(M_1|y_{\text{train}})>0$ we cannot have both sums $\sum_{k=1}^K$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{K+1}$ adding up to $1$.
What am I misunderstanding? Is there a different argument for $(2)$?

Is it not assumed here that $M_k$ are mutually exclusive, maybe after redefining them so that they are?

Thanks for your suggestion. I cannot find any mention that the $M_k$ are mutually exclusive, and in my context I frankly do not even understand what that would mean. I have several competing literal models, built by different (competing) companies, trying to forecast the same timeseries. How would one redefine them so that they are mutually exclusive?

What I had in mind was something like if $M_1$ is $M_2$ with one $\beta=0$ (let's say one of several regression coefficients), one could constrain $M_2$ to have $\beta\neq 0$. I'm not sure it can be applied to all situations. But thinking about it, chances are something else is meant. I try to make an answer of it.

So you already understand that the claim holds if $M_1,\ldots,M_K$ are mutually exclusive.
I have looked up Hoeting, Madigan, Raftery and Volinsky: Bayesian Model Averaging: A Tutorial, http://www.stat.washington.edu/www/research/online/hoeting1999.pdf. There it seems that indeed in all examples models are mutually exclusive in the way I mentioned in the comment, i.e., $M_2$ may be a supermodel of $M_1$ (for example regression with more explanatory variables), but then actually $M_2\setminus M_1$ is considered, $M_1$ is basically taken out of $M_2$ (for example by requiring a regression coefficient to be $\neq 0$). This may not necessarily apply in all situations.
Another way to interpret this is to say that you may have models $M_1,\ldots, M_K$ and a random mechanism that selects a number $K^*$ between 1 and $K$  with prior probabilities $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_K$, and then $M_{K^*}$ generates $y$. So only one of the numbered model list generates $y$, but there is no need that these models are mutually exclusive. Still all the formalism goes through. For example, if in fact $M_1=M_2$ (which would be somewhat pointless but not forbidden), $K^*$ may be either 1 or 2, so that only one of $M_1$ or $M_2$ formally is used for generating $y$, however it would be misleading to say, if $K^*=1$, that "$M_1$ is true and $M_2$ isn't", because they are the same. Rather the exclusivity statement is only about $K^*$ being either 1 or 2.
This actually means that it'd be more correct to write $p(K^*=1)$ rather than $p(M_1)$ as the latter technically would be the same as $p(M_2)$ whereas $p(K^*=1)$ and $p(K^*=2)$ do not need to be the same, i.e., prior probabilities for these may differ, same conditionally under $y_{train}$ or whatever is needed. Of course it also means that $y_{train}$ in fact cannot tell apart $K^*=1$ and $K^*=2$, i.e., $M_1$ and $M_2=M_1$, but this basically means that the (conditional) probability for this model is divided between $K^*=1$ and $K^*=2$ proportionally to the prior probabilities if I'm not mistaken. Admittedly this interpretation would require to be written down slightly differently in order to be formally correct, but I don't think there are further problems.

Thanks for your answer, and for the linked article. Your idea is interesting and seems to make sense. But I'm not yet sure how to commensurate it with my particular situation, where $y$ is generated by an unknown process that is known not to be any of the $M_k$. I'll give it some thought.

@Petr Of course the formal assumption behind all this is that $y$ is indeed generated by one of the $M_k$, but this is not more problematic than all model assumptions in statistics. Generally in reality model assumptions will not perfectly hold. You generally need something like this for deriving theory. Whether something based on certain assumptions will still work well is a matter of the specific situation. At least you can check how well your model averaging does predicting new data that wasn't used for training.

Re: "...but this is not more problematic than all model assumptions in statistics" That's a sad state of affairs, but ok. I'll try to implement it and hope for the best. Your alternative interpretation is certainly helpful and answers my original question, but also confirms that I'll need to modify this BMA approach to suit my needs. Thank you for your help!
